# How do I give my controller function its own template?

Tags: magento

I've built a widget module that has this basic controller:

```
class MyModule_OrderForm_HandlersController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
  public function handleroneAction(){
    // do some stuff
  }
}
```

So this is giving me a page at mydomain.com/orderform/handlers/handlerone which is great, but how do I give that function its own template file.

I've searched Google for hours and not found a straight forward answer, I hope someone here can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for how to create a widget i'd check out http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-magento-widget-part-1/.

But for giving your controller action a template I would check out this article from inchoo:
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programatically-create-magento-blocks-and-inject-them-into-layout/

As the article says the proper 'magento way' is to create a block file in your module that extends `Mage_Core_Block_template` and then insert that block with its template file into the page using layout updates.

The method outlined in the inchoo article lets you skip creating a custom block and layout updates and lets you insert your template directly into the content area of that action.

When you call `$this->loadLayout()` you apply your site's theme to that action.  The template you insert would have everything you want to insert into that page's main content area.

The first param is the type of block you're inserting.In this example we are using `Mage_Core_Block_Template`, the basic block for asigning templates. The second param of the `createBlock() function ('my_block_name_here')` can be any arbitrary name.  The third param is an array of attributes given to the block.  In this example the only attribute we're assigning is 'template'.  this is how we tell the block which template to use.

Comment: Thanks that module in the link provided the answer. I actually didn't want any of the site template around the block, its for a lightbox you see. Any ideas how to stop that coming through?